# Bind a specific Javascript function when using RadAjaxPanel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have this asp.net table row where I use to insert row fields. Now as you can see if I click the add accompanying person in will add a new row. My problem is on the BirthCountry field because I'm using a javascript plugin for that and I can only bind the plugin using the ID field.

The syntax for the plugin is

```
var as = new bsn.AutoSuggest("ContentPlaceHolderDefault_contentMain_newVisaRegistrationID_txtCountry", country);
```

How can I achieve that everytime I click the "Add accompanying person" the specific country field will be binded or loaded with autosuggest initialization script?

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: the brandspankingnew plugin you have chosen cannot easily be modified for the task. i would look into using [jQuery UI autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) You can specify any type of CSS selector with it: an id, a class name or a combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle ajax complete, and then you can attach your event to every element with class="birthCountry" and set them to do autocomplete.
something like this in your case:

```
ajaxcomplete: function(){
   $.each($(".birthCountry"),function(key,value){
      var as = new bsn.AutoSuggest($(value).attr("id"), country);  
   });
};
```